# Anyway to get rid of `math.floor` for positive odd integers with `sympy.simplify`?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to simplify some expressions of positive odd integers with sympy. But sympy refuses to expand `floor`, making the simplification hard to proceed.

To be specific, `x` is a positive odd integer (actually in my particular use case, the constraint is even stricter. But sympy can only do odd and positive, which is fine). `x // 2` should be always equal to `(x - 1) / 2`. Example code here:

```py
from sympy import Symbol, simplify

x = Symbol('x', odd=True, positive=True)
expr = x // 2 - (x - 1) / 2
print(simplify(expr))
```

prints `-x/2 + floor(x/2) + 1/2`. Ideally it should print `0`.

What I've tried so far:

1. Simplify `(x - 1) // 2 - (x - 1) / 2`. Turns out to be 0.
2. Multiply the whole thing by 2: `2 * (x // 2 - (x - 1) / 2)`. Gives me: `-x + 2*floor(x/2) + 1`.
3. Try to put more weights on the `FLOOR` op by [customizing](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html) the `measure`. No luck.
4. Use `sympy.core.evaluate(False)` context when creating the expression. Nuh.
5. Tune other parameters like `ratio`, `rational`, and play with other function like `expand`, `factor`, `collect`.  Doesn't work either.

*EDIT:* Wolfram alpha can [do this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify%28floor%28x%2F2%29-%28x-1%29%2F2%29%2C+x%3E0+and+x%252%3D1).

I tried to look like the assumptions of `x` along with some expressions. It surprises me that `(x - 1) / 2).is_integer` returns None, which means unknown.

I'm running out of clues. I'm even looking for alternativese of sympy. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fail to see why sympy can't simplify that.

But, on another hand, I've discovered the existence of `odd` parameter just now, with your question.

What I would have done, without the knowledge of `odd` is

```py
k = Symbol('k', positive=True, integer=True)
x = 2*k-1
expr = x // 2 - (x - 1) / 2
```

Then, expr is 0, without even the need to simplify.
So, can't say why you way doesn't work (and why that `odd` parameter exists if it is not used correctly to guess that `x-1` is even, and therefore `(x-1)/2` integer).  But, in the meantime, my way of defining an odd integer `x` works.

Comment: Should probably use `2k-1` instead of `2k+1` since we require k to be positive, and `x == 2k+1` means we can't represent `x == 1`.  (Of course, if you remove the positive constraints, then this is irrelevant.)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I need `positive` since OP used `positive` for `x`. But indeed if k is what in my country we call "strictly positive" and in English is called just "positive", then 2k+1 is 3 or more. That is one of the rare examples of math not being exactly an universal language. In English (and in python), 0 is neither positive nor negative. In my country, 0 is both positive and negative (but is not "strictly positive" nor "strictly negative"). Hence the frequent usage in English of "nonnegative" (which is translated as "positive" in my language").

Comment: @AndrewMcClement This even shows with definition of natural number set. In my language, ℕ contains 0 and ℕ* doesn't. While in English ℕ doesn't and ℕ₀ does (but nowadays, to avoid all confusion, maths paper never use ℕ, and only ℕ₀ or ℕ* unambiguous — apparently redundant for half of the readers, but at least unambiguous for all — notations.  But, well, even if I am well aware of those international ambiguities, as you see, I still let them fool me from times to times. So post corrected.

Comment: I think it's a brilliant solution! Though it requires some hacky subtitution to the users' input in my scenario, at least it saves my day! It's interesting to see that sympy requires some "techniques" to get things done...

Comment: It is sufficient to make `k` and integer. And if there are any `k` left after the substitution `(x, 2*k+1)` you can backsubstitute `kexpr.subs(k,(x - 1)/2)` to restore the variable `x`.

Answer (score 0):

There is some reluctance to make too much automatic in SymPy, but this seems like a case that could be addressed (since `(x-1)/2` is simpler than `floor(x/2)`. Until then, however, you can run a replacement on your expression which makes this transformation for you.

Let's define a preferred version of `floor`:

```py
def _floor(x):
    n, d = x.as_numer_denom()
    if d == 2:
        if n.is_odd:
            return (n - 1)/2
        if n.is_even:
            return n/2
    return floor(x)
```

When you have an expression with `floor` that you want to evaluate, replace `floor` with `_floor`:

```py
>>> x = Symbol('x', odd=True)
>>> eq=x // 2 - (x - 1) / 2
>>> eq.replace(floor, _floor)
0
```

Comment: opened as [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24599) at SymPy site